# Any night sky image databases

Tags: observational-astronomy, night-sky

I was wondering if there were any available databases for photos of the night sky. It doesn't have to feature pictures of any particular star, just has to be a large collection of photos from the night sky. I would just go off google images, but those images are heavily biased in favor of exceptional views.

Preferably ones taken from ground level, like pictures of what would be visible to a normal person without equipment.

Comment: Could you specify that a bit? Do you have any particular aim in terms of astronomy/astrophysics? Because there are a number of publicly available archives, like SIMBAD or the Hubble legacy archive, which would satisfy "a large collection of photos from the night sky".

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape Preferably ones taken from ground level, like pictures of what would be visible to a normal person without equipment

Comment: @Alex - google is your best choice for pictures taken from ground level by normal humans. They have millions!

Comment: @RoryAlsop My issue with just using google images is that the images are usually biased towards exceptional scenery/views, I'm just looking for regular pictures

Comment: What people think is exceptional really isn't - have a look through them, you'll rapidly come to the same conclusion.